# My append function does not work as expected. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, append

I am writing my own append function to append a dynamic character array of string array2 at the end of  another dynamic character array of string array1, using a  static char buffer[50]. But the compiler generates the following errors: [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char[50]'. I have tried to figure out the problem, but I don't seem to find the solution. Your help will be very appreciated. I am using Dev-C++. The code is bellow.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

char *Appendstring(char *a, char *b)  // will append b to the end of a
{
    static char buffer[50];
    char *p=buffer=*a++;  //[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char[50]'
                    //[Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'[-fpermissive]
    p--;
    while(*p++=b++);
    p--;  //append
    while(*p++=*c++);
    return buffer;  


}

int main ()
{

    string str="Displaying: ";
    string add=" Summer is coming";

    Appendstring(str, add);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, but why not using `operator +=` for `std::string`s?

Comment: Re-implementing the string class and its members is a common way of learning your way through low level languages like C or C++. I don't see the relevance of pointing out that there's an operator for the described task in order to dismiss the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your append function, the biggest ones are using an array as a pointer and using a static buffer to merge strings. With a static buffer in place, all your merged strings will be in the same space, so merging two strings and then merging the other two would overwrite the results of the first merge!

You can change your function as follows:

```
char *Appendstring(const char *a, const char *b)  // will append b to the end of a
{
    char *buffer = new char[strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1];
    char *p=buffer;
    while(*p++=*a++); // Copy a into buffer
    while(*p++=*b++); // Copy b into buffer right after a
    *p=0; // Null-terminate the string
    return buffer;  
}
```

Of course the caller is responsible for freeing the results of `Appendstring` now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign into an array, which is what you do in `buffer=*a++`. what you meant is probably

```
static char buffer[50];
char *p=buffer;
*p=*a++;
```

In addition, here

```
p--;
while(*p++=*b++);
```

you are trying to derefence a pointer one element *before* the beginning of an array - which leads to undefined behaviour.

Moreover, nowhere do you check for the strings' length, so it can easily be more the 49 together and your code will be both incorrect and insecure (easy victim for [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) attacks).

One last problem is that your code is non reentrant in any way, due to the use of `static` array. you can simply use simple array, if you don't want to adjust it to the strings' length, or allocate it dynamically, as was suggested here.

The best solution of course is to use `std::string` and forget all these problems.